# Bootstrap col-md-2 pushes sixth column down the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Total noob to posting here, and I'm also not wise to the ways of Boostrap, so please bear with me.

Our site uses Bootstrap 3, and I've been instructed to create a page that uses just one custom CSS file that we can package with the page to share with other companies to put on their websites.

I've copied into the custom CSS file everything I can find throughout the site for col-md-# styling, and I have not changed any of the margins, widths, etc., but for some reason when I create six columns of text using the col-md-2 style, the sixth column "wraps" to a new line.

If I understand correctly, I should be able to fit six of the col-md-2 onto one row/line.

I hope I've inserted my screen print and code into my post correctly.

Thanks for any help you can offer this beginner!

UPDATE 6/29/17: I believe I've discovered the problem. I had failed to include some Bootstrap CSS for the body and html tags. Once I included that code, everything fell into place. Thank you, gianni and Thomas!

[image: Last column pushed down]

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-12 {
    right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-11 {
    right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-10 {
    right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-9 {
    right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-8 {
    right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-7 {
    right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-6 {
    right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-5 {
    right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-4 {
    right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-3 {
    right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-2 {
    right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-1 {
    right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-pull-0 {
    right: auto;
  }
  .col-md-push-12 {
    left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-push-11 {
    left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-10 {
    left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-9 {
    left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-push-8 {
    left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-7 {
    left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-6 {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-push-5 {
    left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-4 {
    left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-3 {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-push-2 {
    left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-push-1 {
    left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-push-0 {
    left: auto;
  }
  .col-md-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .md-margin-bottom-10 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .md-margin-bottom-20 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .md-margin-bottom-30 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .md-margin-bottom-40 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .md-margin-bottom-50 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .md-margin-bottom-60 {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 1<br>
    text 2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 3<br>
    text 4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 5<br>
    text 6
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 7<br>
    text 8
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 9<br>
    text 10
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 11<br>
    text 12
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code looks and works fine in pen: https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/NgXjxO
Do you have any other wrappers around it?

Comment: @gianni No. I even copied the page and its CSS file to a different location so they're not sitting within the Bootstrap site, and it still pushes the sixth column so it appears directly under the first column instead of to the right of the fifth column.

Comment: that's strange because I didn't change anything from your code and in my pen it works fine. There may be some css conflict somewhere?

Comment: Are you copying the CSS from the bootstrap.css file?

Comment: Yup, you must be copying the CSS from bootstrap.css this works fine in codepen

Comment: Yes, I copied from the bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some conflicting CSS... To me, it looks like you are copying CSS from bootstrap.css which does not need to be done.

Below is a code pen that has bootstrap 3 setup. I have pasted your code directly into it so you can see that It does work.

https://codepen.io/GuruTom/pen/GEyvrq

Code used:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 1<br>
      text 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 3<br>
      text 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 5<br>
      text 6
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 7<br>
      text 8
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 9<br>
      text 10
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 md-margin-bottom-40">
      text 11<br>
      text 12
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied CSS from bootstrap.css into a standalone, custom CSS file that we're going to package with this single webpage and share with other companies, most of which don't use Bootstrap for their website, so I'm trying to provide them with the CSS they'll need to make the page look like it should. (I tried to explain that in my post, but sorry if I wasn't clear.) So, this page I'm fighting with points only to the custom CSS file, into which I've copied code from boostrap.css. Perhaps I've left something out?

Comment: I would highly recommend not doing that... for the small file that it is just use bootstrap.css (The whole thing) they won't notice a performance drop and it will save you tons and tons of issues down the line